# vite: Unexpected token `React`. Expected jsx identifier

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

Am facing below issue while trying to compile react project which is created using vite library.

```
3:03:53 pm [vite] Internal server error: 
  × Unexpected token `React`. Expected jsx identifier
    ╭─[F:/project/src/main.tsx:7:1]
  7 │ import myTheme from "./components/theme/theme";
  8 │
  9 │ ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
 10 │   <React.StrictMode>
    ·    ─────
 11 │     <BrowserRouter>
 12 │       <ThemeProvider theme={myTheme}>
 13 │         <App title='Solutions' />
    ╰────


Caused by:
    Syntax Error
  Plugin: vite:react-swc
  File: F:/project/src/main.tsx:7:1
```

```
import {React} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App.tsx';
import './index.css';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { ThemeProvider } from "`your text`@mui/material/styles";
import myTheme from "./components/theme/theme";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <ThemeProvider theme={myTheme}>
        <App title='Solutions' />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I tried creating a new react+typescript project with vite and while trying to compile am getting this error

Comment: It should be `import React from 'react';`